# Magento Commerce Cloud What does cname record do in DNS configuration

Tags: magento2-cloud, fastly

I'm going to take the cloud developer certification, and I've been training myselv with some sample tests. there's one question I do not really understand. What is the correct answer in this question? I would choose A. But the correct answer according to the test is B. can someone explain me why B is correct?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure why **B** is the right answer aside from all of the other answers not looking correct.

I mean, the sooner you set a CNAME record, the sooner customers/clients will see the newly migrated site.

A **CNAME** DNS record is just an alias to another (non ip address) DNS record.

Maybe they just mean that when you are instructed to make the change; The sooner it's done, the better, since DNS changes take some time to propagate across the internet.

Comment: if you read this guide about how to enable Fastly (cache), https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/cdn/configure-fastly.html, it actually require to setup the CNAME to enable the cache. That's why I'm wondering why A is not the correct answer.